# Holomorphic function with constant modulus in the boundary of an annulus can be written as $f(z)=cz^n$ for $c\in \mathbb{C}$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I'm preparing myself to take a qualifying exam for my math PHD. I was trying to solve the previous exams and I found a complex analysis problem I couldn't solve:

Let $0<r<R$ and $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|r<|z|<R\}$. Suppose that $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an holomorphic function, with a continuous extension to the boundary of $A$ and such that $f(z)\ne0$ for all $z\in A$. 
Also, suppose that for every $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$ we have $|f(re^{i\theta})|=\alpha$ and $|f(Re^{i\theta})|=\beta$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ don't depend on $\theta$. Prove that for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $c\in\mathbb{C}$ we have $f(z)=cz^n$ for all $z\in A$.

So far, I tried to define a function that scaled the range and domain to fit into the unitary disc and then apply Schwarz's Lemma, but when I tried to prove the differentiability at 0 I noticed it depended on the derivative of $f$ in $re^{i\theta}$, and I can't define $f'$ in the boundary of the annulus, so I gave up on that idea.
Also, the problem has a hint that states: "consider $\log|f(z)|-\gamma\log|z|$ for a convenient $\gamma$". I tried to approach defining a logarithm function, but the domain isn't simply connected so I don't know how to proceed.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

P.S.:This is my first time asking a question on mathstack. If I'm breaking any rule please point it out so I can stop doing it in the future.

Comment: Can you show that $f$ is entire? If so, can you apply the Maximum modulus principle?

Comment: @Bacon  Aren't entire functions defined in the whole complex plane? this one has a bounded domain.

Comment: My ansatz would be to try it with a Laurent series. Your function is holomorphic on a annulus. Hence there is a Laurent series $Q(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{c_n z^n}$ such that $Q=f$ on $A$. Maybe you can proceed now with the Cauchy integral formula (for Laurent series).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this using some theory about harmonic functions. Solve the corresponding Dirichlet problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u = 0 \\
u = \log \alpha, & |z|=r \\
u = \log \beta,  & |z|=R.
\end{cases}
$$
Almost by inspection, the solution is
$$
u = a + b\log|z|
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are chosen to match the boundary conditions. On the other hand, since $f$ is zero-free, $\log|f|$ is harmonic and solves the same Dirichlet problem. By uniqueness (or the maximum principle for harmonic functions), $u = \log |f|$, so
$$
|f| = c|z|^b.
$$
If $f$ is to be holomorphic, argue that $b$ must be an integer. Then finish off by using that if $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic and $|f|=|g|$, then $f = g$ up to a unimodular constant.